# mvnrnd does not generates data with given average and correlation

Tags: matlab, statistics

let us suppose that we have following  vector of averages

```
mu = [2,3]
```

and given correlation matrix

```
sigma = [1,1.5;1.5,3].
```

so we  would have in matlab

```
>> mu = [2,3]
sigma = [1,1.5;1.5,3]

mu =

     2     3


sigma =

    1.0000    1.5000
    1.5000    3.0000
```

now generate Multivariate normal random numbers with the given information

```
rng default  % For reproducibility
r = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,100);
```

but  mean of given matrix

```
>> mean(r)

ans =

    2.1231    3.1217
```

and correlation matrix

```
>> corrcoef(r)

ans =

    1.0000    0.9016
    0.9016    1.0000
```

what is the reason of  such difference? because of small sample size?  thanks in advance

Comment: sigma is the covariance matrix. I think cov is what you want, not corrcoef which returns the correlation factors (hence the 1s in the diagonal) .

Comment: You will never get the true `mu` and `sigma` values from a finite sample. What you are computing from your sample are the [sample mean and sample covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance). These are not the same as the theoretical mean and covariance, but converge to them _in probability_ and _almost surely_ (see the [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)). In other words, it's as if you are told that the average height of Spanish women is 162.6 cm; you take a sample of 100 women and get 163.5. That's perfectly reasonable